# CFBundleIdentifier Collision while uploading a macOS app developed with Electron and built with electron-builder

Tags: macos, phantomjs, electron, mac-app-store, electron-builder

I am currently developing an Electron app and I am able to generate the `.app` and `.pkg` for the macOS operating systems. Although I can run it from the .app generated, when I try to upload the .pkg (**mas**) I get the following error on AppStore Connect:

```
CFBundleIdentifier Collision - 
The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'org.phantomjs' of 'phantomjs'
is already in use by another application.
```

I have tried updating **Electron** to the latest stable version **(2.0.9)**, and updating **electron-builder** to the latest version **(20.28.4)**. I've tried searching for the `org.phantomjs` string in the resulting **.app** and I am unable to find a `Info.plist` with that Bundle Identifier

Here I attach my package.json in case it is useful:

```
{
  "name": "myAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Me <me@mymail.com>",
  "description": "My Description",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./dist/electron/main.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/****.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder",
    "build:dir": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder --dir",
    "build:clean": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=clean node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:web": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=web node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "dev": "node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .js,.vue -f ./node_modules/eslint-friendly-formatter --fix src",
    "pack": "npm run pack:main && npm run pack:renderer",
    "pack:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.main.config.js",
    "pack:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run lint:fix"
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "myAppName",
    "appId": "this.is.a.real.appid",
    "buildVersion": "5",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        },
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.icns",
      "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools",
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "mas"
        }
      ]
    },
    "mas": {
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.icns",
      "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.ico",
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis"
        },
        {
          "target": "appx"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "icon": "build/icons"
    },
    "fileAssociations": [
      {
        "ext": "myExtension",
        "name": "My Project",
        "description": "File containing a My Project.",
        "icon": "build/icons/Project.icns",
        "role": "Editor",
        "isPackage": true
      }
    ],
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Me"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@appshuttle.io/bell": "0.0.12",
    "@appshuttle.io/pollock": "0.0.28",
    "@appshuttle.io/turing": "0.0.16",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "0.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "electron-updater": "^3.0.3",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "p5": "^0.6.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "spectre.css": "^0.5.3",
    "vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-color": "^2.4.6",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^2.5.3",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "cfonts": "^1.2.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "20.28.4",
    "electron-debug": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "multispinner": "^0.2.1",
    "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.3"
  }
}
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution (As mentioned by @countravioli in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3196)):

I found that there was a file called `app.asar.unpacked` that contained multiple Bundle Identifiers once the `.pkg` was created and signed. Deleting this file in the `.app` and then creating a `.pkg` didn't work for me so I used a Build Hook as proposed in the Github Issue. To prevent the file to being inserted to the `.pkg` file. To do this, I added a hook to the build section of my `package.json` at the end of the rest of its contents:

```
package.json
{ //package.json Root ...
   build: {
      // build content ...
      "afterPack": "./afterPack.js"
   }
}
```

An then created a file called `afterPack.js` in the folder where my `package.json` is located with the following contents:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = function (params) {
    const unpackFile = path.join(params.appOutDir, 'YOUR_APP_NAME.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked');
    console.log('EXISTS?', fs.existsSync(unpackFile));
    console.log("REMOVE", unpackFile);
    fse.removeSync(unpackFile);
};
```

I was able to upload the package to AppStore Connect without any issue.

Comment: this will show error on installing